# How does healer work on archer queen?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I have seen attacks where 3 or 4 healers protect queen. Queen doesnot lose any helth at all throught the attack? So does it means if one has enough healers and take out air defenses early somehow, troop(like queen) will last till the end?

**In short**, as long as even a single healer is alive on queen, is she immortal?

***Edit***:- How about healer on BK or other troops?

Comment: When a Healer heals a troop, including a Hero such as BK or AQ, they heal a certain amount of HP depending on the Healer's level. If the amount of cumulative damage from defenses is more than the amount the Healer heals, the troop may lose health. On the other hand, if there aren't too many defenses around, the troop is effectively immortal.

Answer (score 4):

Queen walk is a very effective attack strategy if the attacker has a high level Queen..

We need at least 4 high level healers to make the Queen survive till the end of the attack..She can clear one side of the base easily if she survives the whole 3 minutes...

AQ can take out air defenses before they target the healers.So using a BK or other troops with a bunch of healers wont be much effective...

Hope this helps

Comment: Base defenses can still overwhelm the healing from 4 healers. You need to supplement the 4 healers with rage spells so they can heal the queen more quickly and with larger heals, as well as the queen's active ability, which gives the queen a break from taking damage (and also allows the queen to be healed when next to an inferno tower).